# node js POST with file and string body return 500 error to Angular request

Tags: node.js, angular, post, multipartform-data

i have created the POST service which accept the file and the body as JSON string and it works correctly with Swagger and Postman, but when we try to call it from Angular it returns 500 server error. I do not see anything on the server side log. looks like it get's broken somewhere in the beginning of the post request.
the server part of the code:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {

    cb(null, 'uploads')

},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {

    cb(null, file.originalname)

    fineNameString = file.originalname;

}

})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
router.post('/uploadfile',upload.single('myFile'),function (req,res, next) {
console.log("The request start == " + JSON.stringify(req.body))
const file = req.file;
const body = req.body;
 if (!file) {
    const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
    error.httpStatusCode = 400
    return next(error)
}
else {
 //do work with the file
  }})
```

The front-end part in Angular:

```
 public insertNewBoard(board_name: string, description: string,
                    estimated_time: number, componentFile: File){
let post_address = this.addressData + 'uploadfile';
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
});

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
let board_data = {
  // body data
}
formData.append('myFile', componentFile, componentFile.name);
formData.append('body', JSON.stringify(board_data))

return this.http.post(post_address, formData, {headers: httpHeaders});}
```

this log is not getting printed when the post request is getting called from Angular and i can see all the information when i call it from swagger or postman. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you include more of the front-end and back-end code?

Comment: I've updated both parts, please let me know if any other info could be useful.

Comment: when you append to formData, you should add each key/value pair separately.  If you have a form that contains the file and other values you want to send, it'd be as simple as getting the form by it's id.  ex:  let form = document.getElementById('your_forms_id')! as HTMLFormElement;
let formData = new FormData(form);  No need to set headers when sending formData, it will automatically be set as text/multipart/form-data type.

Comment: to clarify, this "formData.append('body', JSON.stringify(board_data))" is probably causing a malformed request.  Instead, add each value separately... i.e. formData.append('name', 'value');...

Comment: thanks! it was the matter of the header... we removed it and the request have been processed correctly